# Rendering code in Angular 2 template

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on an Angular 2 application and need to display some C# code in an Angular 2 template which will later be styled using a syntax highlighter.

However, as soon as I drop the code into an Angular 2 template I get template parse errors as it tries to parse the C# and fail.

`zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: <code>...`

What is the solution to this? Does Angular 2 include ability to ignore the code portions of my template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<code ngNonBindable>
  code here
</code>
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of interest, are there ways of escaping template reserved characters such as brackets and parenthesis?

Comment: As far as I know only `{{}}` to escape `{` and `}` like `{{'{'}}` and `{{'}'}}`.

Comment: Great, thank you. Thanks for the prompt reply too - I was taking part in a 3 day hackathon and with half an hour left this was a serious sticking point :D

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear :)

Comment: @ Günter, Thanks for answer but I am stucked here as How to write in .html template for the code as---<div>
    <code><pre>
        @Component({
selector: 'app-projection',
  templateUrl: './projection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projection.component.css']
     })
    </code>
  <pre></div>