# How to Display Typescript code in Html

Tags: html, angular

I want to display a component's code in a Html template, Not the value generated by the code but the actual code.

like this

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
    import {CompetitionService} from "../shared/competition.service";
    import {Observable} from "rxjs";


    @Injectable()
    export class TableResolve implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private competitionService:CompetitionService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):Observable<> {
      return this.competitionService.getTeams(route.params['id']);
      }
      }
```

This whole code like they show in stackoverflow in the question section.I tried using `<pre>` and `<code>` but none seem to work ,i am getting this error in console.

```
Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)
```

But if i have to escape it for all { it is problematic please help ?

Comment: also add your component.ts file

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638885/how-to-generate-unrendered-html-elements-on-web-page-with-angular-2-1-1-like-sta/40640828#40640828, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916176/rendering-code-in-angular-2-template/39916193#39916193, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439074/how-to-display-display-htmlnot-parsed-in-angular2-template

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Its a dup i agree but the answers there are a crud way of handling such issues if i have a lot of code to display i guess we need to have library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a variable in your ts file that contains all the code and display it in html using this `{{stringThatContainsAllTheCode}}`

I think the simplest way is to use `[innerHTML]="varContainingCode"` and hold the code in the components class

```
<pre>
  <code [innerHTML]="code"></code>
</pre>
```

```
export class AppComponent {
  code = `   //type script code`
}
```

Or if you don't want to use this library call [ng2-prism](https://www.braceyourself.io/ng2-prism/) can be useful.

This is a Angular2 codeblock highlighting component library.

Comment: My component File is Empty just reference to template and css file that we get when we create component using cli, This is one way thanks but cant i use it directly like static text in my html ?

Comment: @INFOSYS answer updated.
I did some research came across a library that fulfils your needs