# How do I display TypeScript code in "<code>" tags in an Angular app?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to display some TypeScript (angular code) as text on my website using prismjs. But Angular is executing the code. How do I stop it from executing? I have tried wrapping it in pre and code tags but it does not work.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Movie } from './Movie'

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {
      baseUrl='http://127.0.0.1:8000'
      httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type" : 'application/json'})

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getAllMovies(): Observable{
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/movies/", { headers: this.httpHeaders});
      }

      getOneMovies(id): Observable{
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+"/movies/" + id + '/', { headers: this.httpHeaders});
      }

       updateMovie(movie): Observable{
        const body = {id: movie.id, title: movie.title, desc: movie.desc, year: movie.year}
        return this.http.put(this.baseUrl+"/movies/" + movie.id + '/', body, { headers: this.httpHeaders});
      }

      deleteMovie(movie): Observable{
        const body = {id: movie.id, title: movie.title, desc: movie.desc, year: movie.year}
        return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl+"/movies/" + movie.id + '/', { headers: this.httpHeaders});
      }

      addMovie(movie): Observable{
        const body = {id: movie.id, title: movie.title, desc: movie.desc, year: movie.year}
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+"/movies/", body, { headers: this.httpHeaders});
      }
    }
```

Comment: where is your code where you tried to show the `code` in HTML? what are you attempting to display on page? please share some code or a stackblitz to help others understand your problem

Comment: @nircraft If you'd like to submit an answer I will accept it or I will delete this, I will leave it up to you?

Comment: Thanks, see if the answer works for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest of all solutions should be to use a component variable to hold your code and display in HTML using `innerHtml`:

I think the simplest way is to use [innerHtml]="variableHavingCode" and store the code in the components class. And in HTML do this:

```
<pre>
  <code [innerHTML]="code"></code>
</pre>
```

Refered from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597542/9386929)